# Javascript and Web Service Call

Tags: javascript

forgive me if I end up not making any sense but I have no experience with javascript or html.

I have some script that was built for me to be used in a tabbed format which can be seen here henryfarmerscoop.com under Local Grain Markets

My client is wanting to separate the crops so that all can be displayed at once (like in a simple table).

I was wondering if anyone would be able to point me in a direction I can learn how to take the web service call he gave me to incorporate it and make changes on the front end like a table for example instead of the tab.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: It looks like that page is built using wordpress. How is that interface populated now? If you want to use a javascript solution, you're going to need to understand jQuery's $.ajax function (many tutorials in google), and maybe underscore templates (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2411-using-underscore-js-templates-to-render-html-partials.htm)...

Comment: If you have literally no web experience, there's not much that we can do to help besides advise that you learn JS, or hire someone who does.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
if (data[i].Commodity == "Corn")
                        jQuery('#corn_answers').append(row);
                    else if (data[i].Commodity == "Soybeans")
                        jQuery('#soy_answers').append(row);
                    else
                        jQuery('#wheat_answers').append(row);
```

Simply  put

```
jQuery('#corn_answers').append(row);
```

ignoring the "commodity" field.We just add it to one tab. That should start you off.